# Return text, url and image in UIActivityItemProvider

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I am subclassing UIActivityItemProvider for my UIActivityViewController so that when the user selects UIActivityTypeMessage it will only show a message, but if the user selects UIActivityTypeFacebook it will show a message with an image.

This is my code and I can return only a message with UIActivityTypeMessage but for UIActivityTypeFacebook I do not know how to return a message with an Image.

```
- (id)item
{
    if ([self.placeholderItem isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        if ([self.activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage]) {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",self.text,self.url];
        } else {
            NSDictionary *d = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[self.text,self.image] forKeys:@[@"text",@"image"]];
            return d;
        }
    }
    return self.placeholderItem;
}
```

Are there specific keys and values for a UIActivityItemProvider I can use to set the message, url and image?

As an update I read in [UIActivity Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactivity_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIActivityCategory) that there are constants for a specific activity type. Not sure how to use them though. Can someone enlighten me please?

> *UIActivityTypePostToFacebook The object posts the provided content to
>   the user’s wall on Facebook.
>
> When using this service, you can provide **NSString, NSAttributedString,
>   UIImage, ALAsset, and NSURL** objects as data for the activity items.
>   You may also specify NSURL objects whose contents use the
>   assets-library scheme.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create 3 separate activity providers, one for each data type, and pass all of them in in the `initWithActivityItems:applicationActivities:` function on `UIActivityViewController`. 
The activities make use of all the providers you provide, and `UIActivityViewController` hides any one which doesn't support ALL of them (which can make it difficult to only include an image in some cases, for example).